# Provided id of the wrong type for class - [JPA] EmbeddableId formado por outro Embeddable

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-jpa

No banco eu tenho duas tabelas chamadas *TabelaA* e *TabelaB*.
A *TabelaA* é composta por uma chave primaria, que é composta por 3 atributos.
A *TabelaB* é composta por uma chave primaria, que é composta por 3 atributos que também são chave estrangeira, apontando para os 3 atributos de chave primaria da *TabelaA*.
O objetivo é fazer com que a chave primaria da *TabelaB* aponte para a chave primaria da *TabelaA*. Assim como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mapeamento da *TabelaA* está da seguinte maneira:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TabelaA")
public class TabelaA {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TabelaAPK pk;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tabelaA")
    private TabelaB tabelaB;

}


@Embeddable
public class TabelaAPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7143941209658519625L;

    @Column(name = "atributo1")
    private Long atributo1;

    @Column(name = "atributo2")
    private String atributo2;

    @Column(name = "atributo3")
    private Long atributo3;

    public TabelaAPK(Long atributo1, String atributo2, Long atributo3) {
        this.atributo1 = atributo1;
        this.atributo2 = atributo2;
        this.atributo3 = atributo3;
    }

    public TabelaAPK() {}

}
```

O mapeamento da *TabelaB* está da seguinte maneira:

```
@Table(name = "TabelaB")
@Entity
@Data
public class TabelaB{

    @EmbeddedId
    private TabelaBPK pk;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(value = {
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "atributo1", referencedColumnName = "atributo1"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "atributo2", referencedColumnName = "atributo2"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "atributo3", referencedColumnName = "atributo3")
    })
    private TabelaA tabelaA;
}


@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TabelaBPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4788476806371092848L;

    @Embedded
    private TabelaAPK tabelaAPK;

    public TabelaBPK(TabelaAPK tabelaAPK) {
        this.tabelaAPK= tabelaAPK;
    }

}
```

Como podem reparar, o objeto *TabelaBPK* tem o objeto *TabelaAPK* como atributo `@Embedded`.
O objetivo disso é fazer com que caso uma alteração seja feita no objeto *TabelaAPK* essa alteração seja refletida no objeto *TabelaBPK*.

***Problema:*** Quando eu faço uma busca no banco através do trexo de código abaixo, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class TabelaA. Expected: class TabelaAPK, got class TabelaBPK.
```

Código da busca:

```
[...]

String ql = 
        String.format("SELECT b FROM TabelaB b "
                    + "WHERE b.pk.canalPK.atributo1 = %d"
                    + " AND b.pk.pk.atributo2 = '%s'"
                    + " AND b.pk.pk.atributo3 = %d", 
                atributo1, atributo2, atributo3);

return em.createQuery(ql, TabelaB .class).getSingleResult();

[...]
```

- Qual o motivo do problema?
- Como posso resolve-lo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após uma noite de sono acabei encontrando a solução.

O motivo do erro era que o tipo da chave primaria da classe usada na relação `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns` (no caso, a classe *TabelaA*) tem que ser o mesmo tipo utilizado na chave primaria da classe dona da relação (no caso, a classe *TabelaB*).

No meu caso eu estava tentando usar como chave primaria da classe *TabelaB* um classe *TabelaBPK* que é formada pela chave primaria da classe *TabelaA*, a *TabelaAPK*, porém isso não irá funcionar pois a classe *TabelaAPK* precisa ser chave primária direta da classe *TabelaB*.